# I want to use elastislide inside accordion with multiple instances at a time

Tags: jquery, css

If i use either elastislide / Accordion (with multiple instance) at a time, its working fine. But if i try to use both at the same time, im getting problem.  Here is my link http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/vxt4g/9/ Can any one help me 2 fix it.

```
    $('#carousel').elastislide();

    $("#accordion").addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget")
        .find("h3")
        .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-top")
        .hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover");
    })
    .prepend('<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"></span>')

    .click(function () {
        $(this).find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-s").end()

    .next().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active").slideToggle();
    return false;
    })
    .next()
    .addClass("ui-accordion-content  ui-widget-content")
    .hide();
```

Comment: what is problem,fiddle looks proper\

Comment: Elastislide is not working properly.. Images were too small in accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. now both accordion and elastislide were working fine..

Along with js, in CSS also i made changes and **Working Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/vxt4g/22/**

```
    $("#accordion").addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget")
         .find("h3")
        .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default")
        .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
        .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"></span>')

         click(function() {
         $(this)
         .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default")
         .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e ui-icon-circle-triangle-s").end()
        .next().slideToggle();
          return false;
        })

       .next()
       .addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content")
       .hide();
```